# How do I find unique traces from a csv dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, unique

I have a csv file which contains log data. In which there are only two columns that I am intrested in `'case:concept:name'`, `'concept:name'`.Here I basically want to find unique traces and how many time those unique traces are repeating in the csv.

I was able to sort `'case:concept:name'` with respect to index so I can visualize the steps in sequential format.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("D:\Task\B.csv")

df = data[["case:concept:name","concept:name"]]

df.head()

sort = df.rename_axis('MyIdx').sort_values(by = ['case:concept:name','MyIdx'], ascending = [True, True])

sort.head(50)
```

I basically want the count of all unique steps.How many times those unique steps are repeated throughout the data.

Comment: Could you please give an output example?

Comment: @kantal  (register request,examine thoroughly,check ticket,decide,reject request)^2(Power 2) here this basically means this 5 things repeated twice in whole data set and so on....

Comment: @kantal you can save output in new csv file also where it must specify how many times a individual trace is repeating in sequence in whole data set....

Comment: @kantal brother any update....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the case number, convert the task names in group into a tuple and count them in a dictionary:

```
 ...
df = data[["case:concept:name","concept:name"]]
dfg= df.groupby(["case:concept:name"])
dd={}
for k,v in dfg:
    print(f"Key:{k} ---> {v}")          # inspection
    print(type(v))                      # inspection
    print(type(v["concept_name"]),"\n") # inspection
    t=tuple(v["concept:name"])
    dd[t]=dd.get(t,0)+1

for process,count in dd.items():
    print(f"{process}: {count}")

Output example:
    ('register request', 'examine thoroughly', 'check ticket', 'decide', 'reject request'): 2
    ('register request', 'check ticket', 'examine casually', 'decide', 'pay compensation'): 1
...

To save it, e.g:

with open("helpdesk_out.csv","w") as fout:
    # using ';' as delimiter
    fout.write("process;count\n")
    for process,count in dd.items():
        proc=str(process).replace("'","")
        fout.write(f"{proc};{count}\n")
```

**EDIT 1:**
We can use the previously created 'dd' to count the pairs. (You can write out the result in the same way as before.)

```
d2={}
for t,cnt in dd.items():
    t2= zip(t,t[1:])   # pairing
    for proc2 in t2:
        d2[proc2]=d2.get(proc2,0)+cnt
```

**EDIT 2:**
Rows are grouped by the case number aka "case:concept:name".
To clear it, some print instruction are inserted into the code above, tagged as "inspection".
The "k" is the key, and "v" is the grouped rows forming a DataFrame.

```
Key:1 --->    case:concept:name        concept:name
0                  1    register request
1                  1  examine thoroughly
2                  1        check ticket
3                  1              decide
4                  1      reject request
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Key:2 --->    case:concept:name      concept:name
5                  2  register request
6                  2      check ticket
7                  2  examine casually
8                  2            decide
9                  2  pay compensation
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

etc.
```

v["concept:name"] is a Series and we convert it into a tuple, eg.:
('register request', 'examine thoroughly', 'check ticket', 'decide', 'reject request')
Then in a dictionary we count the occurrence of each tuple. Here the key will be the tuple self, and the value will be the occurrence (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict).

**EDIT 3:**
You can do it more "pandas" way, too:

```
ser= df.groupby(["case:concept:name"]).apply(lambda g: tuple(g["concept:name"]))
print(ser.value_counts())

Output example:
(register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request)      2
(register request, check ticket, examine thoroughly, decide, reject request)      1

ser2= pd.Series( [ p for t in ser for p in zip(t,t[1:]) ] )
print(ser2.value_counts().sort_index())

Output example:
(check ticket, decide)                      7
(check ticket, examine casually)            2
(check ticket, examine thoroughly)          1
```

Comment: The output file is not saving correctly. I want ('register request', 'examine thoroughly', 'check ticket', 'decide', 'reject request') all in one cell and the count number in another cell 2.But correctly each are getting save in individual cell like 'register request' one cell , 'examine thoroughly' another cell and so on...

Comment: Why don't you adjust the output format to your liking yourself?

Comment: Assuming that you import the output into a spreadsheet, you can  specify ';' as delimiter.

Comment: @kantal Okay I done that but now i have one more question for example lets say (a,c,d,e,f) trace is 30 times,(a,b,c,e,f) trace is 20 times and (a,b,e,f) trace is 5 times now I have to make pair for above (a,c,d,e,f) as (ac,cd,de,ef) and so on for the next one as (ab,bc,ce,ef) and for next one (ab,be,ef) after that I have to count how many times ab is present in whole data. For current scenario ab=25 and ef=55 present and so on i want as output.Do you know how to do that...If so kindly help..

Comment: @kantal I am getting output something like this '''('register request', 'examine thoroughly', 'check ticket', 'decide', 'reject request'): 1
('register request', 'examine thoroughly', 'check ticket', 'decide', 'reject request'): 1
('register request', 'examine thoroughly', 'check ticket', 'decide', 'reject request'): 1
('register request', 'examine thoroughly', 'check ticket', 'decide', 'reject request'): 1('register request', 'examine thoroughly', 'check ticket', 'decide', 'reject request'): 1
''' But i want like this ('register request', 'examine thoroughly') : 1

Comment: @kantal Hi would you please explain how the flow of above code works....

Comment: @Ani What part do you think of?

Comment: @kantal What exactly you are doing here --  df = data[["case:concept:name","concept:name"]]
dfg= df.groupby(["case_concept:name"])
dd={}
for k,v in dfg:
    t=tuple(v["concept_name"])
    dd[t]=dd.get(t,0)+1

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something like this?

```
df.groupby(["concept:name"]).count().reset_index()
```

output:

```
concept:name    case:concept:name
check ticket        9
decide              9
examine casually    6
examine thoroughly  3
pay compensation    3
register request    6
reinitiate request  3
reject request      3
```

OR Output 2:

```
df.groupby(["case:concept:name"]).count().reset_index()
```

Output

```
case:concept:name   concept:name
1                   5
2                   5
3                   9
4                   5
5                   13
6                   5
```

Comment: I want output something like this ('register request', 'examine thoroughly', 'check ticket', 'decide', 'reject request'): 2
    ('register request', 'check ticket', 'examine casually', 'decide', 'pay compensation'): 1 here the first one which comprises of 5 traces repeated 2 times in whole data set(above considered repeating only if all the same i am getting somewhere else in the data) and write the same in csv file....